# iOS can I increment an NSNumber, or do I need to create a new one?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, increment, nsnumber

**Is there a way to increment a NSNumber instance in place without having to create a new number ?**

Here's what I'm doing currently:

```
    int photoIndex = hour + minute/30;
    NSNumber* currentCount =  [self.photosByTime objectAtIndex:photoIndex];

    [self.photosByTime replaceObjectAtIndex:photoIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentCount.intValue +1]];
```

Is there a way to do the increment without having to replace the array contents every time?

Comment: NSNumber object are immutable so what you are doing right now is the right way..

Comment: I believe you can do this too: [self.photosByTime replaceObjectAtIndex:photoIndex withObject:@(currentCount.intValue +1)]];

Comment: Or you can do `[self.photosByTime replaceObjectAtIndex:photoIndex withObject:@(@([self.photosByTime[photoIndex]).integerValue + 1)];` There are many other ways ;) But to answer your question there is no way to manipulate an instantiated `NSNumber` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right, as NSNUmber's are not mutable, so there has to be a new one fo every change.

Comment: Seriously!? Wow, I never knew that.